# How to use the /r flag in Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

The Perl doc states:

```
e  Evaluate 'replacement' as an expression
r  Return substitution and leave the original string untouched.
```

are available flags to be used in replacement patterns. When I pass the `r` flag to my substitution pattern, it gets interpreted as a syntax error. I am running Perl 5.8.8. Is it possible it is not supported in my version of Perl? Also, can someone provide a working example of how to use the flag and how to call the newly created replacement?

Comment: From The Effective Perler: [Use the /r substitution flag to work on a copy](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/09/use-the-r-substitution-flag-to-work-on-a-copy/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps you should be reading the docs for 5.8.8, then? /r was added to 5.14!

In 5.8.8, you can do the equivalent of

```
s/foo/bar/r
```

with

```
do { (my $s = $_ ) =~ s/foo/bar/; $s }
```

---

Sample usages of s///r:

```
print "abba" =~ s/b/!/rg;         # Prints a!!a

my $new = $old =~ s/this/that/r;  # Leaves $old intact.

my $trimmed = $val =~ s/^\s+//r =~ s/\s+\z//r;
my $trimmed = (($val =~ s/^\s+//r) =~ s/\s+\z//r);  # Same as previous
```

Comment: Could you show how to call it in 5.14. I'm confused on how it returns a different variable, but you still have to notate the variable to run it on. For example:

    $var =~ s/this/that/r;
Where does the new variable get saved?

Comment: @user1671989, It gets returned. «`print "abc" =~ s/b/!/rg;`» prints «`a!c`».

Comment: So if it gets returned and I called it like

$var =~ s/this/that/r;

it would indeed overwrite $var?
How can I run it on $var and return it to $new_var? Sorry for being a noob, having trouble wrapping my head around it.

Comment: `my $new_var  = ($var =~ s/this/that/r;);`


like that?

Also, unrelated, how can I markup code in a SO comment?

Comment: Yes, you could do that. That would leave `$var` intact, and place the new value in `$new_var`. /// Wrap it in backticks, or indent by 4 spaces. (Ctrl-K will indent a swath of code for you.)

Comment: @user1671989 Head wrapping: It's no different from `$a = f($b)` ... `$b` is an input value and the result is stored in `$a`. `sub f{ $_[0] =~ s/this/that/r} my $new_val = f($var)`  does the same as your statement.